# Compiling FreeType for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, config, freetype

I'm using FreeType on Windows, Linux and OSX without a single problem, and now I was to port my tech to IOS...
And I can't find a way to have FreeType compiled for it.

At first I tried to drop every FT file into my project, but that clearly didn't work.

Then I tried to make a static library following [this tutorial here](http://robertcarlsen.net/2009/03/25/openframeworks-iphone-libs-593).
While I can't test if it worked for the arm target, it doesn't work for the simulator target.

When trying to link the built library into XCode it says "libfreetype-simulator.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386)"
and that's ok because the command "lipo -info libfreetype-simulator.a" tells me that the file was built for x86_64.
I tried configuring it with "./configure --i386-apple-darwin", [here's the log](http://pastebin.com/LViXr2qg).
But still, the resulting arch was x86_64.

How in the world can I build freetype for i386, iphone simulator?
I really have no clues.

Comment: See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11856736/406356) to this similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2740733/compiling-freetype-for-iphone-sdk-xcode/11856736#11856736

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I used the [link in cxa's answer](http://librocket.com/wiki/documentation/BuildingFreeTypeForiOS). However it is very out of date, and my configure line did not fit in a comment. For armv7, compiling with the 6.1 SDK, with a minimum version of 5.1, without bzip2, you want something like:

```
./configure '--without-bzip2' '--prefix=/usr/local/iphone' '--host=arm-apple-darwin' '--enable-static=yes' '--enable-shared=no' 'CC=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc' 'CFLAGS=-arch armv7 -pipe -std=c99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O2 -Wreturn-type -Wunused-variable -fmessage-length=0 -fvisibility=hidden -miphoneos-version-min=5.1 -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk/usr/include/libxml2/ -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk/' 'AR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ar' 'LDFLAGS=-arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk/ -miphoneos-version-min=5.1'
```

Note the lack of `-mdynamic-no-pic` which would otherwise produce a linker warning, and a warning email from Apple, if left in. Also note that various pathnames have changed.

Comment: +1 for the -mdynamic-no-pic part as this might be problematic https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1788/_index.html#/apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013354

Comment: I've logged in to SO after years and I have updated the correct answer, thanks!

Answer (score 12):

I came across this project today while trying to compile FreeType for iOS: https://github.com/cdave1/freetype2-ios

Just download, open in xcode, and compile.  :)

Hope this is helpful for anyone else trying to compile for iOS.

Answer (score 5):

For Xcode 5, gcc has moved location so the configuration should be:

```
./configure --without-zlib --without-png --without-bzip2 '--prefix=/usr/local/iPhone' '--host=arm-apple-darwin' '--enable-static=yes' '--enable-shared=no' 'CC=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang' 'CFLAGS=-arch armv7 -pipe -std=c99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O2 -Wreturn-type -Wunused-variable -fmessage-length=0 -fvisibility=hidden -miphoneos-version-min=6.1 -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/usr/include/libxml2/ -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/' 'AR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ar' 'LDFLAGS=-arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.0.sdk/ -miphoneos-version-min=6.1'
```

The location of CC can be found by running:

```
$ xcrun -find -sdk iphoneos clang
```

Answer (score 4):

For iOS SDK 8.1 with a min target of 7.1 on Xcode 6.1, this works:

```
./configure --without-zlib --without-png --without-bzip2 '--prefix=/usr/local/iPhone' '--host=arm-apple-darwin' '--enable-static=yes' '--enable-shared=no' 'CC=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang' 'CFLAGS=-arch armv7 -pipe -std=c99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O2 -Wreturn-type -Wunused-variable -fmessage-length=0 -fvisibility=hidden -miphoneos-version-min=7.0 -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/usr/include/libxml2/ -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/' 'AR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ar' 'LDFLAGS=-arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/ -miphoneos-version-min=7.0'
```

Answer (score 4):

Maybe someone will find it usefull.
 SDK 8.1, XCode 6.1 
i386,x86_64,arm64 (for profiling) ,armv7,armv7s

```
./configure CFLAGS="-arch i386"
make clean
make
cp objs/.libs/libfreetype.a libfreetype-i386.a

./configure CFLAGS="-arch x86_64"
make clean
make
cp objs/.libs/libfreetype.a libfreetype-x86_64.a

./configure --without-zlib --without-png --without-bzip2 '--prefix=/usr/local/iPhone' '--host=arm-apple-darwin' '--enable-static=yes' '--enable-shared=no' 'CC=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang' 'CFLAGS=-arch armv7 -pipe -std=c99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O2 -Wreturn-type -Wunused-variable -fmessage-length=0 -fvisibility=hidden -miphoneos-version-min=7.0 -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/usr/include/libxml2/ -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/' 'AR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ar' 'LDFLAGS=-arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/ -miphoneos-version-min=7.0'
make clean
make
cp objs/.libs/libfreetype.a libfreetype-armv7.a

./configure --without-zlib --without-png --without-bzip2 '--prefix=/usr/local/iPhone' '--host=arm-apple-darwin' '--enable-static=yes' '--enable-shared=no' 'CC=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang' 'CFLAGS=-arch arm64 -pipe -std=c99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O2 -Wreturn-type -Wunused-variable -fmessage-length=0 -fvisibility=hidden -miphoneos-version-min=7.0 -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/usr/include/libxml2/ -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/' 'AR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ar' 'LDFLAGS=-arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/ -miphoneos-version-min=7.0'
make clean
make
cp objs/.libs/libfreetype.a libfreetype-arm64.a

./configure --without-zlib --without-png --without-bzip2 '--prefix=/usr/local/iPhone' '--host=arm-apple-darwin' '--enable-static=yes' '--enable-shared=no' 'CC=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang' 'CFLAGS=-arch armv7s -pipe -std=c99 -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O2 -Wreturn-type -Wunused-variable -fmessage-length=0 -fvisibility=hidden -miphoneos-version-min=7.0 -I/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/usr/include/libxml2/ -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/' 'AR=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/ar' 'LDFLAGS=-arch armv7s -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.1.sdk/ -miphoneos-version-min=7.0'
make clean
make
cp objs/.libs/libfreetype.a libfreetype-armv7s.a

lipo -create -output libfreetype.a libfreetype-i386.a libfreetype-x86_64.a libfreetype-armv7.a libfreetype-armv7s.a libfreetype-arm64.a
```

Answer (score 2):

[This shell script](https://github.com/jkyin/Compile-Freetype-For-iOS/blob/master/build_freetype.sh) works for me, x86_64. You maybe need to have a look.

I used it to compile freetype2.5.5, and got armv7, arm64, i386, x86_64.Of course it lipo to  a single fat static library.

Comment: Thanks!  Your answer seems to be the only remaining working solution, as of sept 2015

Answer (score 0):

For freetype to compile smoothly it's important to pass the variables 'CC', 'CFLAGS', 'LDFLAGS' and 'AR' as arguments to `configure` and **not** as environment variables.

at some point `configure` runs the native gcc of the machine and if you have 'LDFLAGS' that point to the iphone SDK it will cause it to fail. passing the variables to `configure` seems to solve this issue.