# Static FreeType has dependencies (libfreetype.6.dylib)

Tags: xcode, macos, freetype

On OSX here. Building with make.

My settings:

```
./configure --enable-static=yes --enable-shared=no
```

I've changed nothing else from the vanilla FreeType 2.5.3 download.

This results in libfreetype.a and when added to a project (link binary with libraries) I get all sorts of build errors that I don't get with a shaded library:

```
"_BZ2_bzDecompress", referenced from:
  _ft_bzip2_file_fill_output in libfreetype.a(ftbzip2.o)
 "_png_create_info_struct", referenced from:
  _Load_SBit_Png in libfreetype.a(sfnt.o)
"_inflateInit2_", referenced from:
  _FT_Stream_OpenGzip in libfreetype.a(ftgzip.o)
```

Etc., etc.

So it get's stranger, if I build with this ./configure:

```
./configure --enable-static=yes --enable-shared=no  --with-png=no --with-bzip2=no --with-zlib=no
```

Then I can build my project okay, but when I run it I get an error saying that /opt/local/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib could not be found. Well of course not, because that's only built with a shared FreeType build.

How can I build an entirely dependency free FreeType (like the website says you can)?

Many thanks,
Ian

Comment: I'm working around the problem by using a shared FreeType library. It seems a bit daft that the static version of FreeType looks for the shared version!?

Comment: I managed to get a static lib of FreeType working, I've posted an answer...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found success - eventually - by adapting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28030547/1375695)  and adding exclusions for `blib`.`png`,`bzip`

Ignoring the iOS pieces...

```
./configure CFLAGS="-arch i386" --without-zlib --without-png --without-bzip2
make clean
make
cp objs/.libs/libfreetype.a libfreetype-i386.a

./configure CFLAGS="-arch x86_64" --without-zlib --without-png --without-bzip2
make clean
make
cp objs/.libs/libfreetype.a libfreetype-x86_64.a

lipo -create -output libfreetype.a libfreetype-i386.a libfreetype-x86_64.a
```

This has worked for me using a mix of FreeType 2.5.5 + Yosemite + Xcode 6.2

Comment: This approach worked for me, but I had to also add the `--without-harfbuzz` flag to the configure commands. Thanks!

Comment: Just to follow up in the year 2023, today I needed this configure:

freetype-2.13.1: ./configure --without-zlib --without-png --without-bzip2 --without-harfbuzz --without-brotli

(list now has without-brotli as well)