# How can I use Freetype2 successfully on Mac?

Tags: ios, xcode, truetype, freetype

I want to use Freetype to do a single demo in iOS using Xcode 9.1.

```
error = FT_New_Face(library, "myxcode path.TTF", 0, &face);
```

(I build it in terminal (Mac), reference the http:   [Static FreeType has dependencies (libfreetype.6.dylib)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26888332/static-freetype-has-dependencies-libfreetype-6-dylib)
 and  Github  https://github.com/jkyin/Compile-Freetype-For-iOS and then I close the bitcode in Xcode, add the zip static lib, and so on to resolve the zip ...bug ....then I can use it preliminary).

But when I write the code:

```
FT_Library  library;  
FT_Face     face;  

error = FT_Init_FreeType(&library);  //cross

// 2. 
error2 = FT_New_Face(library, "my proj path.TTF", 0, &face);
```

This error2 return 1. That means I can not open the resource. I promise that I set the plist and building phase and add the freetype.a (arm64). Why does it return 1? I have the file. Why can not open it? I build the freetype2.7 so many times and change other ftt,oft (from Mac font).

I hope  ft_new_face return 0   (I use Xcode 9, Mac 11+, Freetype 2.7).

Comment: Is "my proj path.TTF" a placeholder for the full path to the ttf, or are you making an assumption about the current working directory?

Comment: i use the full and local path,but no use