# Cocoa - How to extract data from otf file?

Tags: cocoa, fonts, metadata

I would like to know how to extract the metadata of an otf file. For example :

- chrono number of the glyphs (ex: 001, 002...)
- associated unicode in hexadecimal
- etc..

Applications like "Font Examiner" can do it :

[Font Examiner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AaaA4.png)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If this were my problem I'd probably want to solve it using as much public and/or open source code as possible.

For example, you can use the [FreeType library](http://www.freetype.org/index.html) (which apparently compiles for both Macintosh [& iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425643/compiling-freetype-for-iphone) to [load the .otf font](http://freetype.sourceforge.net/freetype2/docs/tutorial/step1.html), then you can get the metadata off the loaded face (e.g. [the `num_glyphs` attribute in FTFace_rec](http://freetype.sourceforge.net/freetype2/docs/reference/ft2-base_interface.html#FT_FaceRec)).

If you can load the font into a NSFont or UIFont instance, you do have access to a [`numberOfGlyphs`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSFont_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSFont/numberOfGlyphs) and a [`coveredCharacterSet`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSFont_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSFont/coveredCharacterSet) property (the latter shows the characters a font can render).