# Error compiling freetype2 library for arm7 with OSX gcc: `limits.h: No such file or directory

Tags: ios, xcode, gcc, freetype2, arm7

I am trying to compile the `freetype2` library for arm7, using Xcode's command line tools in OSX. I am using the following parameterisation of the project's `configure` script:

[Compiling FreeType for iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6425643/compiling-freetype-for-iphone/16817138#16817138)

These errors were produced when running the script:

> configure:3426: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc -E  conftest.c
>   In file included from conftest.c:10:
>   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/llvm-gcc-4.2/bin/../lib/gcc/i686-apple-darwin10/4.2.1/include/limits.h:15:25: error: limits.h: No such file or directory
>
> configure:3426: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc -E -traditional-cpp  conftest.c
>   conftest.c:12: error: assert.h: No such file or directory
>
> configure:3426: /lib/cpp  conftest.c
>   /Volumes/DATA/filestore/development/libs/c/freetype2/extract/2.5.3/builds/unix/configure: line 1600: /lib/cpp: No such file or directory
>
> configure:3465: result: /lib/cpp
>   configure:3485: /lib/cpp  conftest.c
>   /Volumes/DATA/filestore/development/libs/c/freetype2/extract/2.5.3/builds/unix/configure: line 1600: /lib/cpp: No such file or directory

I can see that the missing files actually do exist in the directories output in the error messages.

`CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` contain the following parameter, which should allow for the inclusion of system header files:

> -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk/

The other odd thing that I noticed with these error messages, is that the architecture identifier in the directory structures is `i686-apple-darwin10`. The `-arch armv7` compiler flag is being used, so why are `i686-apple-darwin10` directories being inspected at all?

*** UPDATED ***

I also tried parameterising the `configure` script as per another example:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12594507/1704014

The following error terminated its execution:

> checking for suffix of native executables... ld: library not found for -lcrt1.10.6.o
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>   configure: error: native C compiler is not working

This also indicates that a different target architecture (OSX 10.6) is being built against, not arm7.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in my OSX build environment was the Xcode command line tools installation. I reinstalled the latest distribution of the tools, and was able to compile successfully from then on.

To build the freetype2 library for arm7 and arm7s architectures, I found the following suggested commands useful:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/12594507/1704014